# Закрытие блока div при клике вне него

Tags: javascript

Есть всплывающий блок, который нужно закрывать, при клике вне него, вот код закрытия на крестик, здесь все нормально закрывает

```
document.getElementById('cancel').onclick=function(){
        var container = document.getElementById('prompt-form-container');
        hideCover();
        container.style.display = 'none';         
    }
```

А вот  код закрытия при клике вне блока

```
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
window.onclick = function(event) {

    if (event.target == modal) {

        modal.style.display = "none";


}
    }
```

И когда я кликаю вне блока, блок скрывается, но фон позади остается затемнен и кликнуть нигде нельзя